# Jquery Datatable show / hide

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have bunch of bootstrap tabs ( dynamically generated with knockout ), each tab content area has a table ( dynamically generated with knockout ). I have a check box on top of the tab panel which says "Enable Paging". Checking this box will execute a function and jquery data table https://datatables.net shows up and everything looks great. When i UNCHECKED the box it does not goes away. Please note i only want to remove the data table ( paging, searching and all that ) not the actual data. Here is code :

```
                $('#isPagingEnabled').click(function () {
                    if(this.checked){
                        showPaging();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hidePaging();
                    }
                });


                function showPaging(){
                    $('table').filter(function(index){
                        $('#dataTable'+index).dataTable(); //this works perfectly..
                    });

                }

                function hidePaging(){ // **this is not hiding / removing datatables**
                    $('table').filter(function(index){
                        $('#dataTable'+index).dataTable( {
                            "retrieve": true,
                            "destroy": true,
                            "paging":   false,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info":     false
                        } );
                    });

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to change hidePaging() function and add the call to fnDestroy(false) and it worked.

```
                 function hidePaging(){
                    $('table').filter(function(index){
                        var dt =   $('#dataTable'+index).dataTable( {
                            "retrieve": true,
                            "destroy": true,
                            "paging":   false,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info":     false
                        } ).**fnDestroy(false)**;
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can check the checkboxes 'status' by using the function prop(). For example:

```
if($(this).prop('checked')){
 showPaging();
}
```

Comment: showPaging() and hidePaging() is executing properly. its just datatable which is not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to evaluate whether the box is checked or not is

```
$('#isPagingEnabled').click(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    showPaging();
  } else {
    hidePaging();
  }
});
```

To destroy the dataTable, change your hidePaging function:

```
function hidePaging() {
   $('table').filter(function(index) {
     $('#dataTable'+index).DataTable().destroy();
   });
});
```

I found that information here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

You were re-initializing the dataTable.

Comment: showPaging() and hidePaging() is executing properly. its just datatable which is not hiding.